# How to create a schedule task to scan malware on a specific folder?

Tags: deepsecurity

based on existing post, it is understood that currently to scan malware through API using DeepSecurity, we are required to create a Schedule Task.

May I know is it possible to configure the Schedule Task to scan malware on a specific folder ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a group

1. Go to DSM console.
2. Click on "Computers" in the left sidebar.
3. Click on "Create Group(s)..." and configure the group settings.
4. Go back to the computers page.
5. Select your host and click on "Details...".
6. Under "Group", select the group you just created and click "Save".

Step 2: Schedule a malware scan

1. Go to "Scheduled Tasks" and click "New...".
2. Select "Scan Computers for Malware" as the task type.
3. Choose the frequency of the scan and click "Next".
4. Configure the task details (recommended to not set the timeout to "Never") and click "Next".
5. Select "In Group" and pick the group you just created, then click "Next".
6. Click "Finish" to complete the task creation.